# Manipulating records generated using user defined function

Tags: sql, oracle, row, records

I have a table with below records.

```
A   B       C       D       E   F
------------------------------------
1   asd     dff     Dfdf    Rt  Rtrt
1   ads     Dfd     df      Drt Trtrt
1   cvc     Fd      Df      Dff Rtrt
2   cvc     Df      Df      Dfd Fg
2   ree     Ddfd    Df      Fd  Hgh
3   cv      Df      Fdf     Fdf B
3   rt      Wew     Fd      Df  N
3   rti     Yuiyu   Fd      Dfd Bnh
3   uyiuy   uyii    Dfdf    df  hhh
```

Suggest a query(user defined function) that would would provide me the output as

```
A   B       C       D       E   F
------------------------------------
1   asd     dff     Dfdf    Rt  Rtrt
1   ads     Dfd     df      Drt Trtrt
1   cvc     Fd      Df      Dff Rtrt

2   cvc     Df      Df      Dfd Fg
2   ree     Ddfd    Df      Fd  Hgh

3   cv      Df      Fdf     Fdf B
3   rt      Wew     Fd      Df  N
3   rti     Yuiyu   Fd      Dfd Bnh
3   uyiuy   uyii    Dfdf    df  hhh
```

A blank row after every similar value for column A.

Comment: Have a look at [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: This would be a job for whatever tool or system you're using to render the output of your sql.